# Topolgical insulators order parameter

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-order, topological-insulators, topological-phase

*For topological insulators*
**Is there any way to define [order parameter for topological phase transitions](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=order+parameter+topological+phase+transition)?**

Comment: One should clarify that: Topological insulator is NOT topologically ordered, but topological insulator is ONLY symmetric-protected (U(1) charge and time reversal). Such a transition is not a  topological phase transition as the nature of (fractional) quantum hall states.

Comment: You can not define a local order parameter. However, you can finds some topological invariants 
(http://http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.3895), which distinguish the phases.

Comment: Yes, the order parameter is the (global) topological invariant ($\nu_{0}=0,1$) introduced by Fu, Kane, and Mele: http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0607699 for time-reversal symmetric free fermion systems. In (say) Bi$_{1-x}$Sb$_{x}$ alloys, the topological invariant can be defined as a function of $x$. As you increase $x$ from zero, for some $x=x_{c}$, a phase transition will occur and $\nu_{0}$ will change from 0 to 1.